# What's the benefit of doing import package.submodule?

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

Using `numpy` as an example, I can't seem to realize what the benefit of doing an import like this would accomplish:

```
import numpy.lib
```

after the import finishes, `numpy` is available as a name, equivalent to if you imported it directly:

```
import numpy
```

in *both* cases, you can access the submodule `lib` only with dotted access:

```
>>> numpy.lib
<module 'numpy.lib' from ....>
```

is there a case where doing `import numpy.lib` would be beneficial?

Comment: `import numpy` imports all numpy submodules, including those you do not use. `import numpy.lib` imports only `numpy.lib`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

The actual effect depends on how the module is implemented.  The outer module  might or might not import sub-packages.  See the [tutorial section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) on packages for details.

### Example Directory Structure

For example, here is a possible directory structure

```
outer
├── outer/__init__.py
└── outer/inner
    └── outer/inner/__init__.py
```

### Case where outer/__init__.py is empty

```
>>> import outer               # only loads outer
>>> import outer.inner         # loads both outer and inner
```

### Case where outer/__init__.py loads the submodule

If the `outer/__init__.py` file contains `from . import inner`, then you get:

```
>>> import outer               # loads both outer and inner
>>> import outer.inner         # loads both outer and inner
```

### Specific case from NumPy

The *numpy* module matches the second case, so `import numpy` and `import numpy.lib` have the same effect.  Here is an except from numpy's __init__.py file:

```
from . import core
from .core import *
from . import compat
from . import lib
from .lib import *
from . import linalg
from . import fft
from . import polynomial
from . import random
from . import ctypeslib
from . import ma
from . import matrixlib as _mat
from .matrixlib import *
from .compat import long
```

### Conclusion

In the specific case of *numpy*, **`import numpy` and `import numpy.lib` have the exactly the same effect.**

Hope that clears it up for you :-)

Comment: Ah, so the difference is that `import numpy.lib` would execute both `numpy/__init__.py` if it exists and `numpy/lib/__init__.py` if that exists?